# C++ input integer print unicode

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

I'm trying to output Unicode that corresponds to an integer value entered by the user. This is being done on windows 10 in C++ by the way.
Currently I can print Unicode with this code:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

wprintf(L"\u0006");'''
```

My question is, how do I attach the variable to the Unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
wchar_t wstr[2] = { variable, L'\0' };
wprintf(L"%ls", wstr);
```

Alternatively, you can avoid the expense of `wprintf` with

```
wchar_t wstr[2] = { variable, L'\0' };
fputws(wstr, stdout);
```

In both cases `variable` is the integer variable you mentioned. You might want to check that is in range for a `wchar_t` and you might want to add a cast to suppress any compiler warning.

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand. Are you not familar with null terminated strings, with printf style formatting, with array initialisation?

Comment: Never mind that, I was being stupid. It's just that its giving me errors when i try it.

Comment: OK, well I haven't tested anything, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry still half asleep, it should be fixed now.

Comment: I've tested it now, it's working for me. I didn't know about `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` so that's good to learn.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have just realized that this code fails to output the correct Unicode characters, unlike the code I first posted.

Comment: @Lachy314 Not sure why that would be, the code constructs a string that should be identical to the hard coded strings in your question. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Well, maybe it's because I'm using a int type variable, but I not too sure. For example i try code 2230 which is this ∰ but instead I get this  ࢶ.

Comment: @Lachy314 Is this a decimal/hexadecimal confusion? 2230 is a hexadecimal value, the decimal equivalent is 8752.

Comment: Ahhhh, I just realized that, thanks. So why does my first code output ∰  but not the second, when I enter the same values. Is there a base difference between both?

Comment: @Lachy314 Yes, the number in `"\uNNNN"` is hexadecimal